# PayPal Checkout example code error: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk

Here is the code I'm using which I obtained from https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/integrate/

```
 <script
                src="https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=<?= $paypalID; ?>&currency=GBP"> 
              </script>

              <div id="paypal-button-container"></div>

              <script>



                paypal.Buttons({
                    createOrder: function(data, actions) {
                      // This function sets up the details of the transaction, including the amount and line item details.
                      return actions.order.create({
                        purchase_units: [{
                          amount: {

                            "value": "<?= $grandTotalOP; ?>"
                          }
                        }]
                      });
                    },
                    onApprove: function(data) {
                        console.log(data);

                        var theBody = {'orderID' : data.orderID};
                        theBody = JSON.stringify(theBody);

                      return fetch('/capture-paypal-transaction', {
                        headers: {
                          'content-type': 'application/json'
                        },
                        method: "POST",
                        body: theBody
                      }).then(function(res) {
                         console.log('test');
                         console.log(res);
                        return res.json();
                      }).then(function(details) {
                        alert('Transaction funds captured from ' + details.payer_given_name);
                      })
                    }
                  }).render('#paypal-button-container');

              </script>
```

i am getting this error in the console

> js?client-id=AaLa1ylO5YjAUByNm_epTAh3MDAmQ0o9UAoqGdPy2kgS-syd8KbJIcmk8QYpAeE99ZzgEnOfaPdoYfGe&currency=GBP:1
>   Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
>
> Error: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
>       at ur. (https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=AaLa1ylO5YjAUByNm_epTAh3MDAmQ0o9UAoqGdPy2kgS-syd8KbJIcmk8QYpAeE99ZzgEnOfaPdoYfGe&currency=GBP:1:295788)
>       at Object. (https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=AaLa1ylO5YjAUByNm_epTAh3MDAmQ0o9UAoqGdPy2kgS-syd8KbJIcmk8QYpAeE99ZzgEnOfaPdoYfGe&currency=GBP:1:302957)
>       at JSON.parse ()
>       at o (https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=AaLa1ylO5YjAUByNm_epTAh3MDAmQ0o9UAoqGdPy2kgS-syd8KbJIcmk8QYpAeE99ZzgEnOfaPdoYfGe&currency=GBP:1:302816)
>       at wr (https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=AaLa1ylO5YjAUByNm_epTAh3MDAmQ0o9UAoqGdPy2kgS-syd8KbJIcmk8QYpAeE99ZzgEnOfaPdoYfGe&currency=GBP:1:302969)
>       at Ir.l.on (https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=AaLa1ylO5YjAUByNm_epTAh3MDAmQ0o9UAoqGdPy2kgS-syd8KbJIcmk8QYpAeE99ZzgEnOfaPdoYfGe&currency=GBP:1:307996)
>       at Ir (https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=AaLa1ylO5YjAUByNm_epTAh3MDAmQ0o9UAoqGdPy2kgS-syd8KbJIcmk8QYpAeE99ZzgEnOfaPdoYfGe&currency=GBP:1:308185)
>       at https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=AaLa1ylO5YjAUByNm_epTAh3MDAmQ0o9UAoqGdPy2kgS-syd8KbJIcmk8QYpAeE99ZzgEnOfaPdoYfGe&currency=GBP:1:313190
>       at https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=AaLa1ylO5YjAUByNm_epTAh3MDAmQ0o9UAoqGdPy2kgS-syd8KbJIcmk8QYpAeE99ZzgEnOfaPdoYfGe&currency=GBP:1:313236
>
> Error: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
>       at ur. (https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=AaLa1ylO5YjAUByNm_epTAh3MDAmQ0o9UAoqGdPy2kgS-syd8KbJIcmk8QYpAeE99ZzgEnOfaPdoYfGe&currency=GBP:1:295788)
>       at Array. (https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=AaLa1ylO5YjAUByNm_epTAh3MDAmQ0o9UAoqGdPy2kgS-syd8KbJIcmk8QYpAeE99ZzgEnOfaPdoYfGe&currency=GBP:1:302957)
>       at JSON.parse ()
>       at o (https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=AaLa1ylO5YjAUByNm_epTAh3MDAmQ0o9UAoqGdPy2kgS-syd8KbJIcmk8QYpAeE99ZzgEnOfaPdoYfGe&currency=GBP:1:302816)
>       at wr (https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=AaLa1ylO5YjAUByNm_epTAh3MDAmQ0o9UAoqGdPy2kgS-syd8KbJIcmk8QYpAeE99ZzgEnOfaPdoYfGe&currency=GBP:1:302969)
>       at Ir.l.on (https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=AaLa1ylO5YjAUByNm_epTAh3MDAmQ0o9UAoqGdPy2kgS-syd8KbJIcmk8QYpAeE99ZzgEnOfaPdoYfGe&currency=GBP:1:307996)
>       at Ir (https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=AaLa1ylO5YjAUByNm_epTAh3MDAmQ0o9UAoqGdPy2kgS-syd8KbJIcmk8QYpAeE99ZzgEnOfaPdoYfGe&currency=GBP:1:308185)
>       at https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=AaLa1ylO5YjAUByNm_epTAh3MDAmQ0o9UAoqGdPy2kgS-syd8KbJIcmk8QYpAeE99ZzgEnOfaPdoYfGe&currency=GBP:1:313190
>       at https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=AaLa1ylO5YjAUByNm_epTAh3MDAmQ0o9UAoqGdPy2kgS-syd8KbJIcmk8QYpAeE99ZzgEnOfaPdoYfGe&currency=GBP:1:313236

and this is the response from the server

> Fatal error   Uncaught PayPalHttp\HttpException:
>   {"error":"invalid_client","error_description":"Client
>   Authentication failed"} in
>   /home/MYSERVER/public/vendor/paypal/paypalhttp/lib/PayPalHttp/HttpClient.php:215
>   Stack trace:
>   #0 /home/MYSERVER/public/vendor/paypal/paypalhttp/lib/PayPalHttp/HttpClient.php(100):
>   PayPalHttp\HttpClient->parseResponse(Object(PayPalHttp\Curl))
>   #1 /home/MYSERVER/public/vendor/paypal/paypal-checkout-sdk/lib/PayPalCheckoutSdk/Core/AuthorizationInjector.php(37):
>   PayPalHttp\HttpClient->execute(Object(PayPalCheckoutSdk\Core\AccessTokenRequest))
>   #2 /home/MYSERVER/public/vendor/paypal/paypal-checkout-sdk/lib/PayPalCheckoutSdk/Core/AuthorizationInjector.php(29):
>   PayPalCheckoutSdk\Core\AuthorizationInjector->fetchAccessToken()
>   #3 /home/MYSERVER/public/vendor/paypal/paypalhttp/lib/PayPalHttp/HttpClient.php(64):
>   PayPalCheckoutSdk\Core\AuthorizationInjector->inject(Object(PayPalCheckoutSdk\Orders\OrdersGetRequest))
>   #4 /home/MYSERVER/public/public/capture-paypal-transaction.php(23): PayPalHttp\HttpClient- in
>   **/home/MYSERVER/public/vendor/paypal/paypalhttp/lib/PayPalHttp/HttpClient.php**
>   on line **215**

here is the server code which is taken from the paypal docs link at the top

```
  <?php

namespace Sample;

require_once '/home/MYSERVER/public/vendor/autoload.php'; 

//1. Import the PayPal SDK client that was created in `Set up Server-Side SDK`.
use Sample\PayPalClient;
use PayPalCheckoutSdk\Orders\OrdersGetRequest;

class GetOrder
{

  // 2. Set up your server to receive a call from the client
  /**
   *You can use this function to retrieve an order by passing order ID as an argument.
   */
  public static function getOrder($orderId)
  {

    // 3. Call PayPal to get the transaction details
    $client = PayPalClient::client();
    $response = $client->execute(new OrdersGetRequest($orderId));
    /**
     *Enable the following line to print complete response as JSON.
     */
    //print json_encode($response->result);
    print "Status Code: {$response->statusCode}\n";
    print "Status: {$response->result->status}\n";
    print "Order ID: {$response->result->id}\n";
    print "Intent: {$response->result->intent}\n";
    print "Links:\n";
    foreach($response->result->links as $link)
    {
      print "\t{$link->rel}: {$link->href}\tCall Type: {$link->method}\n";
    }
    // 4. Save the transaction in your database. Implement logic to save transaction to your database for future reference.
    print "Gross Amount: {$response->result->purchase_units[0]->amount->currency_code} {$response->result->purchase_units[0]->amount->value}\n";

    // To print the whole response body, uncomment the following line
    // echo json_encode($response->result, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
  }
}

/**
 *This driver function invokes the getOrder function to retrieve
 *sample order details.
 *
 *To get the correct order ID, this sample uses createOrder to create a new order
 *and then uses the newly-created order ID with GetOrder.
 */

if (!count(debug_backtrace()))
{
  GetOrder::getOrder('REPLACE-WITH-ORDER-ID', true);
}
?>
```

Comment: This is your primary error: `{"error":"invalid_client","error_description":"Client Authentication failed"}`  You need to do some debugging to narrow down why.

Comment: Thanks @PatrickQ after posting i did figure that out but im a little unsure how to debug it at the moment... im still thinking... i was really hoping that someone here would have the answer. From my point of view, the server side script is not correct. I need to look further into the documentation but surely someone here can point me in the right direction???

Comment: surely there would be somewhere in the server script where i should put the client secret?

Comment: I am not convinced the invalid_client error is a primary error. The "<" opener, which could be a PHP one, being processed as JSON, could be the root cause of things.

Comment: @FeelsUnique  We probably need to see your `PayPalClient` class.  Also, can you show the response in your network inspector for the request to `https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=AaLa1ylO5YjAUByNm_epTAh3MDAmQ0o9UAoqGdPy2kgS-syd8KbJIcmk8QYpAeE99ZzgEnOfaPdoYfGe&currency=GBP`

Comment: @FeelsUnique  Regarding the client secret, you did go through all of the [server-side SDK setup](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/reference/server-integration/setup-sdk), right?  Because there's a line in the code that has `$clientSecret = getenv("CLIENT_SECRET") ?: "PAYPAL-SANDBOX-CLIENT-SECRET";` which would address that.

Comment: @FeelsUnique  Ignore my request for the network inspector response from `https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id`

Comment: @PrestonPHX  By default, PHP fatal errors are going to be sent back as HTML.  That is most definitely the cause of the JS errors, because the JS is expecting a JSON response.  If PHP wasn't executing, we wouldn't be getting the PHP error stacktrace.

Comment: Agreed (question didn't specify if this was during the order creation or after approval, so I reviewed the creation portion first, which doesn't have an XHR to server PHP.  The server-side PHP stack trace wasn't clearly formatted before, but I think you improved the question to show it better)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the solution

```
<?php

namespace Sample;

require_once '/home/server/public/vendor/autoload.php'; 

//1. Import the PayPal SDK client that was created in `Set up Server-Side SDK`.
use Sample\PayPalClient;
use PayPalCheckoutSdk\Orders\OrdersGetRequest;
use PayPalCheckoutSdk\Core\PayPalHttpClient;
use PayPalCheckoutSdk\Core\SandboxEnvironment;


ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL); // or error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
ini_set('display_startup_errors', '1');

class PayPalClient
{
    /**
     * Returns PayPal HTTP client instance with environment that has access
     * credentials context. Use this instance to invoke PayPal APIs, provided the
     * credentials have access.
     */
    public static function client()
    {
        return new PayPalHttpClient(self::environment());
    }

    /**
     * Set up and return PayPal PHP SDK environment with PayPal access credentials.
     * This sample uses SandboxEnvironment. In production, use LiveEnvironment.
     */
    public static function environment()
    {
        $clientId = getenv("CLIENT_ID") ?: "CLIENT_ID-here";
        $clientSecret = getenv("CLIENT_SECRET") ?: "CLIENT_SECRET-here";
        return new SandboxEnvironment($clientId, $clientSecret);
    }
}


class GetOrder
{

  // 2. Set up your server to receive a call from the client
  /**
   *You can use this function to retrieve an order by passing order ID as an argument.
   */
  public static function getOrder($orderId)
  {

    echo "testtttt ".$orderId;
    // 3. Call PayPal to get the transaction details
    $client = PayPalClient::client();
    $response = $client->execute(new OrdersGetRequest($orderId));
    /**
     *Enable the following line to print complete response as JSON.
     */
    print json_encode($response->result);
    print "Status Code: {$response->statusCode}\n";
    print "Status: {$response->result->status}\n";
    print "Order ID: {$response->result->id}\n";
    print "Intent: {$response->result->intent}\n";
    print "Links:\n";
    foreach($response->result->links as $link)
    {
      print "\t{$link->rel}: {$link->href}\tCall Type: {$link->method}\n";
    }
    // 4. Save the transaction in your database. Implement logic to save transaction to your database for future reference.
    print "Gross Amount: {$response->result->purchase_units[0]->amount->currency_code} {$response->result->purchase_units[0]->amount->value}\n";

    // To print the whole response body, uncomment the following line
    // echo json_encode($response->result, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
  }
}

/**
 *This driver function invokes the getOrder function to retrieve
 *sample order details.
 *
 *To get the correct order ID, this sample uses createOrder to create a new order
 *and then uses the newly-created order ID with GetOrder.
 */
$request_body = file_get_contents('php://input');
$data = json_decode($request_body);
print_r($data);
echo 'order id = '.$data->orderID;
if (!count(debug_backtrace()))
{
  GetOrder::getOrder($data->orderID, true);
}
?>
```